# I need to pick numbers out of a long string

Tags: c++, file

I have a string of about a thousand digits in a .txt file. I need to evaluate one digit at a time, compare it with adjacent digits, then move down the list and do it again. I'm using C++ and the get() function. Here's what I have so far:

```
int element[5];
ifstream file;

file.open("theNumber.txt", ios::in);
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    file.seekg(1);
    element[i]=file.get();
}
//read first 5 numbers.
```

Right now my code won't compile, and showing it all would make most of you cry, but I wanted to check to see if This part was correct. Will this give me an array with the first five digits of the number in the file?

Comment: Why don't you try running it in isolation?

Comment: Adding compile errors would be a good start. So would searching them on Google. `ifstream::get()` returns a character casted to an integer too, so if the first number was '0', `element[0]` would be 48.

Answer (score 3):

> Will this give me an array with the first five digits of the number in the file?

No, your `seekg` call is setting the read position to the second character every time you call it; just throw that call away (`get()` automatically advances the read position).

You also need to handle the text to binary conversion. Easiest to do like this:

```
int ch = file.get();
if (ch < '0' || ch > '9')
{
    // Handle invalid input or EOF/error...
}
element[i] = ch - '0';
```

Answer (score 2):

> Will this give me an array with the first five digits of the number in the file?

No, sorry. It will give you the second digit of the file, five times over.

There are [two versions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/) of `seekg`: one that sets the file pointer's position from the beginning and one that sets it relative to some other position. The line `file.seekg(1);` sets the file pointer to absolute position 1: the second byte of the file. Thus your array contains the same digit repeated.

Consider changing the `1` to `i` in the call, if you want to use that particular `seekg` overload.

Good luck.

---

Also, as Brendan and spencercw note, you'll still have to convert the ASCII code.